# Drawing Stage behind 3d scene in libgdx

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am trying to draw a stage (with a parallax effect) behind my 3d scene in libgdx (as a background). When I call `stage.draw()` before `screen.render()` i can only see the 3d scene. When I call `screen.render()` before `stage.draw()` i can only see the background. Is there a way to make the screen somehow see through?

I am calling:

```
stage.act();
stage.draw();
screen.render(delta);
```

My `render()` operation in screen looks like this:

```
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
modelBatch.begin(mainCamera);
modelBatch.render(instances, environment);
modelBatch.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out: 
Instead of calling `stage.act()` and `stage.draw()` before `screen.render()`,
 I simply called `stage.act()` and `stage.draw()` in the `render()` operation after  
`Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`